# Static methods for Biz layer (ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-access-layer

Dear All,
Actually I have done all my Biz(business layer) and DAL CRUD Opprations using static methodes
and I just send my error messages to my log table

a sample of biz layer

```
public static bool Delete(Guid LogGroupID)
    {
        using (DAL.ChroXEntities db = new ChroX.DAL.ChroXEntities())
        {
            var q = (from lg in db.LogGroupSet
                     where (lg.LogGroupID == LogGroupID)

                     select lg).FirstOrDefault();
            if (q != null)
            {

                try
                {
                    db.DeleteObject(q);

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    GeneralClass.LogError(ex);
                }


            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

so what should i do to propagate an user friendly error to my users?
thanks for ever,
Kiarash

Comment: `var q = db.LogGroupSet.FirstOrDefault(lg => lg.LogGroupID == LogGroupID);`

Comment: what is that for? it is just another way ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User friendly all depends on the context so from your biz-layer you should simply re-throw your exception

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   GeneralClass.LogError(ex);
   throw;
}
```

Then higher up in your hireachy where you're actually calling your Delete method from, you should again have a try-catch statement but here in your catch you should extract the message and write it out to the user, either as html, a ajax-popup or whatever. As i said, user friendly all depends on the context, which you haven't told us much about here.